# Mahout and custom table for data model

Tags: java, mysql, mahout

The documentation says that the table of ratings should look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE taste_preferences (
  user_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
  item_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
  preference REAL NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (user_id, item_id)
);
```

However, in my implementation table of ratings is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE taste_preferences (
  profile_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
  event_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
  status_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (user_id, item_id)
);
```

Where the grade is in the form status_id (go, no go, maybe I'll go).

The users table as follows:

```
 CREATE TABLE user (
  profile_id_1 BIGINT NOT NULL,
  profile_id_2 BIGINT NOT NULL,
  profile_id_3 BIGINT NOT NULL,
  ...
);
```

A user can have multiple profiles, I need to compare these data to users.

I need to write its own implementation of data model? Which way do I see, that would solve this problem? Thanks!

Comment: I want to use MySQL as a data model. I want users to compare their status at the events. But my table does not seem to ratings on that, as described in the documentation.
How to make your implementation of the data?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have rating data here, in any form. So, you can't use ratings in recommendations. That's fine; you just have "boolean" data.

Or, you're saying you need to use status but I'm not clear how you want to use it.

You can certainly use your `taste_preferences` table. Just use `MySQLBooleanPrefJDBCDataModel` or similar. The `user` table is irrelevant.